# Upload File using PHP into Amazon S3 bucket - without using SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i need to upload a file, into an Amazon S3 bucket, using PHP code,
but i need to do that without using the SDK (Version 3).

i cannot use the SDK version 3, because i have PHP version 5.3.3 on my server.

All links, guides and examples, in the Amazon S3 website, are referring to the SDK.
how can i upload a file without using the SDK?

thank you.

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Comment: compile alternative php in cgi mode can run any number of versions

Comment: The SDK is open sourced so you can see how it works. I think the hard part is not the actual upload which is pretty easy (it's just a post at a specific endpoint) it is generating the authentication signature.

Comment: use the curl command to upload an image to s3 with access key and secret key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's how you upload an object to S3 using S3 API.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html) You don't need to use an SDK for this. Just send an HTTPS request as per the documentation.

Comment: This is the term i was looking for and didn't know it existed : "Amazon S3 REST API". this is all i needed to read about and go forward. thank you.